# How to create a Dataflow template pipeline with Beam 2.0?

Tags: templates, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Dataflow 1.9 used to have a `TemplatingDataflowPipelineRunner`, but Beam doesn't. What are the steps to create a Dataflow template pipeline using the Beam 2.0 Java SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Beam 2.0, use the `DataflowRunner` and specify a `--templateLocation`:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.myclass \
 -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
              --project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID] \
              --stagingLocation=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/staging \
              --output=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/output \
              --templateLocation=gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/templates/MyTemplate"
```

Note that `--templateLocation` replaces the previous `--dataflowJobFile`.

See the Dataflow documentation on [Creating and staging templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates) for Java SDK 2.X